# Create a query params with combobox in Foxx

Tags: swagger, arangodb, joi, foxx

I wonder if I can create a query param that take multiple values from dropdown just like a non-typing combobox in the UI of ArangoDB. For example

```
//A route....
.queryParam('A', joi.any().allow(["true","false,"haha"]).required().default("true"))
```

The one above produce an dropdow that allow you to choose only 1 value. Is it possible to make them behave like a combo box on arango's UI?

Answer (score 0):

I use this query param join's validation that shows as a drop down in the Arango UI

```
.queryParam('direction', joi.string().lowercase().valid('inbound', 'outbound', 'any')
.required().description('Direction of traversal from given product (inbound/outbound/any)'
    ))
```

[image: Sample Arango UI showing a drop down]

Comment: I would like to be able to choose more than one value. In your example, it would be both inbound and outbound. The desired behaviour would be similiar to a multiple combobox